# How to set default collation for mysql xampp, windows

Tags: mysql, xampp

Hi I ran into this question and could not get an answer. How can you set default, server-wide collation for your MySQL database for XAMPP+Windows.

Answer (score 1):

What I have figured out. Look for my.ini file in your mysql folder, bin subfoler (e.g. E:\xampp\mysql\bin). Backup your my.ini file and open it for edit, then look for following:

```
character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Here you can change your collation to the desired default value. Save edits and restart MySQL.